# Css @keyframe can not work with JQuery at same time :(

Tags: jquery, css

Thank for your attention. I want to make the img which is

```
<img id=IMGR1 class=bounceMe src="image/DoubleArrowDown.png" width="180px" height="180px" alt="DoubleArrowDown">
```

could have the bounce animation and when it clicked it could rotate 180 deg and keep bounce animation.

Now it only bounce but not rotate when I click it. only rotate when I disable the bounce animation. Thank in advanced.

Here is my code

---

`HTML`

```
  <section class="mybackground">
            <div id="TA">
                <div class="TheatreArt">
                    <div class="text1">
                    <h3>Theatre Art</h3>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="TheatreArtcard">
                    <h4>Bringing Imagination to Life</h4>
                    <img id=IMGR1 class=bounceMe src="image/DoubleArrowDown.png" width="180px" height="180px" alt="DoubleArrowDown">
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

`CSS`

```
.bounceMe {
    animation: arrowDown .67s infinite;
}

@keyframes arrowDown {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);

    }

    50% {
        transform: translateY(6px);

    }

    50% {
        transform: translateY(3px);

    }

    75% {
        transform: translateY(6px);

    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

---

`JQuery`

```
$(".TheatreArtcard").on("click", function () {
    var h = $('.TheatreArtcard').css('height');
    var image = document.querySelector("#IMGR1");
    console.log("test001");

    if (h == '465px') {
        $(".TheatreArtcard").animate({height: "560px"});
        image.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)"; 
        // $(".text").css("display", "none");
        $(".text1").css("background-color", "rgba(33, 37, 36, 0)");
        $(".text1 h3").css("color", "#fafaef00");
        document.querySelector(".text1").style.backdropFilter = "blur(0px)";



        console.log("test002");

    }

    else {
        $(".TheatreArtcard").animate({height: "465px"});
        image.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)"; 
        $(".text1").css("background-color", "rgba(33, 37, 36, 0.527)");
        $(".text1 h3").css("color", "#fafaef");
        document.querySelector(".text1").style.backdropFilter = "blur(10px)";
        
    }
    
    
});
```